# How to override jQuery UI Datepicker :before and :after stylings

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating jQuery widget that wraps the existing datepicker and I am trying to append a `<div>` around the calendar and the title that exist directly inside the `#ui-datepicker-div` element that parents everything. The problem is it looks like they have a built in CSS styling to clear content before and after these elements:

```
.ui-helper-clearfix:before, .ui-helper-clearfix:after {
content: "";
display: table;
}

.ui-helper-clearfix:after {
clear: both;
}
```

These appear to be the CSS culprits that are clearing my `<div>` directly after I append it using jQuery. I tried setting the content property to normal, but it continues to clear everything. I'm not too familiar with the clear and content CSS properties so someone probably knows what my problem is.

Comment: It might be their JS which still adds the styling, eventhough you have removed it from CSS file.

Comment: Hmmm. That is true. I may have to override it in my JS as well.

Comment: So something else that is strange. A second ago I was able to see my new `div` being added around the correct elements, but all of a sudden the elements I am trying to wrap don't exist until after `beforeShow` ever gets called. I'm confused